# Remove a word from a file

Tags: python, file

I am try to sort through the following file

```
Fantasy
Supernatural
Fantasy
UrbanFantasy
Fantasy
EpicFantasy
Fantasy
HighFantasy
```

I want to remove the word fantasy when it appears by **itself** and put the new list into another file
I tried

```
def getRidofFantasy():
    file = open("FantasyGenres.txt", "r")
    new_file = open("genres/fantasy", "w")
    for line in file:
        if line != "Fantasy":
            new_file.write(line)
    file.close()
    new_file.close()
```

This does not work and I am at a lost as to why. The new file is the same as the old one. Can anyone explain what's happening and give an example of the correct solution?

Comment: Try `if line.strip() != "Fantasy":`, there will be newline chars at the end of each line that you want to strip

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with open('fantasy.txt') as f, open('generes/fantasy', 'w') as nf:
  lines = [line+'\n' for line in f.read().splitlines() if line != "Fantasy"]
  nf.writelines(lines)
```

In your code when you do `for line in f` the `line` variable also include the `\n` (endline) char, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. -

```
def getRidofFantasy():
    with open("FantasyGenres.txt", "r") as file:
        content = [line.strip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
        new_list = list(filter(lambda a: a != 'Fantasy', content))

    with open("genres/fantasy.txt", "w") as new_file:
        [new_file.write(f'{line}\n') for line in new_list]
    
getRidofFantasy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Atin's answer, you can also do this:

```py
with open('fantasy.txt') as f, open('generes/fantasy', 'w') as nf:
  lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if line.strip() != "Fantasy"]
  nf.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because a new line is also a character:

```
Fantasy\n
Supernatural\n
etc.
```

You have to account for that. One possibility:

```
def getRidofFantasy():
    with open("FantasyGenres.txt", "r") as f:  # this way Python closes the file buffer for you
        oldfile = f.readlines()
    new_file = open("genres/fantasy", "w")
    for line in oldfile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line != "Fantasy":
            new_file.write(line+'\n') # make sure to append the newline character again
    
    new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there is one thing you should know. When you read a line like that the variable will look something like this:-
`line='Fantasy\n'`

So, you need to strip that character. The simple solution without changing any of  your code would be to just change the if statement. Change it to
`if not 'Fantasy'== line.strip()` and keep your code as it is and the new file that'll be generated will be the one you want.